# AdjustViewBounds works for android:src not android:backgound in imageview

Tags: java, android, imageview

I've got an imageview which has different images as source and background. When I use adjustviewbounds and scaletype, it works fine on the image added in the source but not the one in the background. How can I make it work for the background image too?

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailSocial"
        android:src="@drawable/videopost"
        android:background="@drawable/coldplay"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: `adjustViewBounds` and `scaleType` works only with source image (`src`) not with background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to divide background and src image to two separate view. But top view with transparent background

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnailSocial"
    android:layout_width="199dp"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/coldplay" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/videopost" />
</RelativeLayout>
```